# Accessing web pages on Azure VM

Tags: azure, hosting, web-hosting

I would like to have my webserver on AzureVM. I will use multiple sites via host header.

Bindings: All unassigned and host header = www.site.com

My VM is configured and sites running locally (I can show website on erver in IIS.. Browse...) with no problem. Endpoints are configured too. Default web page of IIS is accessible on address .cloudapp.net
Problem:
I cant access my second website from internet:
service.cloudapp.net/www.site.com (this is maybe wrong)

service.cloudapp.net.www.site.com

service.cloudapp.net.www.site.com.

Nothing working :-(
Haw can i access it?

Thank you in

Comment: Voted to move this to ServerFault. This is more about administration/configuration than programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple websites hosted on the same IIS Server.

To access the websites individually over the Internet, you need to suffix the DNS Name with the Public Port.

For Example :

DNS Name : myvm.cloudapp.net

Website 1 : myvm.cloudapp.net:52477

Website 2 : myvm.cloudapp.net: 51998

However if you are using Host Headers in IIS, you might want to refer to the below link which gives more insight

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433110.aspx

Hope this helps !

Regards,

Sowmya

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. After some experiments... Second solution is: Make reserved IP for AzureVM and use host Names in IIS. In your domain must be two row: @ A IP and second row: www  A  IP.All working with default port: 80 and 443.